# setuptools finds wrong package during install

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

In [myria-python](https://github.com/uwescience/myria-python), we use setuptools with `install_requires` to configure which packages are needed. In our particular [setup file](https://github.com/uwescience/myria-python/blob/master/setup.py), we include `requests-toolbelt` and `requests` in that list.

When we create a new virtual environment and then run `python setup.py install`, it fails the first time with `Cannot find required distribution requests`. This happens seemingly because `pip` identifies `requests toolbelt-0.3.1` (note the space) as the right match for package `requests`.

Running `python setup.py install` again seems to install `requests` after all.

Here is [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/uwescience/myria-python/issues/16) with a full log of the install process.

Steps to reproduce:

- `git clone https://github.com/uwescience/myria-python.git`
- `cd myria-python`
- `mkvirtualenv myria-python`
- `python setup.py`

The entire lab seems to have this issue, however all of us use Mac OS X with either 10.9 or 10.10 installed. Here are my machine's specs:

- OS X 10.10.1
- Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 23:46:04)
- pip 1.5.6
- mkvirtualenv 1.11.6

I was also able to duplicate it on one of our Ubuntu servers:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l
- Python 2.7.6
- pip 1.5.4
- mkvirtualenv 1.11.4

Here is the tail of the error log:

```
Searching for requests-toolbelt
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests_toolbelt/
Best match: requests-toolbelt 0.3.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/requests-toolbelt/requests-toolbelt-0.3.1.tar.gz#md5=e563377e46cd0be8c7b3ac144a65844c
Processing requests-toolbelt-0.3.1.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/m_/qltd_g_13qd1v5tvr4l6q2rc0000gn/T/easy_install-2lqn7g/requests-toolbelt-0.3.1/setup.cfg
Running requests-toolbelt-0.3.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/m_/qltd_g_13qd1v5tvr4l6q2rc0000gn/T/easy_install-2lqn7g/requests-toolbelt-0.3.1/egg-dist-tmp-riz25e
no previously-included directories found matching '*.pyc'
warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 6: 'recursive-include' expects <dir> <pattern1> <pattern2> ...

warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 7: 'recursive-include' expects <dir> <pattern1> <pattern2> ...

no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding requests-toolbelt 0.3.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Users/dhalperi/Envs/myria-python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_toolbelt-0.3.1-py2.7.egg
Searching for requests
Best match: requests toolbelt-0.3.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/requests-toolbelt/requests-toolbelt-0.3.1.tar.gz#md5=e563377e46cd0be8c7b3ac144a65844c
Processing requests-toolbelt-0.3.1.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/m_/qltd_g_13qd1v5tvr4l6q2rc0000gn/T/easy_install-LKxX9E/requests-toolbelt-0.3.1/setup.cfg
Running requests-toolbelt-0.3.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/m_/qltd_g_13qd1v5tvr4l6q2rc0000gn/T/easy_install-LKxX9E/requests-toolbelt-0.3.1/egg-dist-tmp-3tgz5e
no previously-included directories found matching '*.pyc'
warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 6: 'recursive-include' expects <dir> <pattern1> <pattern2> ...

warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 7: 'recursive-include' expects <dir> <pattern1> <pattern2> ...

no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
requests-toolbelt 0.3.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /Users/dhalperi/Envs/myria-python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_toolbelt-0.3.1-py2.7.egg
error: Could not find required distribution requests
```

How can I fix this so that the package installs without running setup.py twice?

Comment: Are you running `python setup.py install` and then `pip setup.py install` or are you running `python setup.py install` twice? In your question you first refer to Python directly and then to Pip.

Comment: Thanks @Timusan; I typoed `pip` instead of `python`. I am running `python setup.py install` twice.

Comment: I think I have seen this one of my own projects. It might be a bug in pip (or related software) regarding version parsing. Might try at pip issue tracker? Also sometimes having confusion regarding uppercase and lowercase and dash vs. underscore in package name confuses Python packacge installers, though pip has been doing good job here lately.

Comment: I can relate to what @MikkoOhtamaa said, one of my projects suffered from a bug in Pip with this exact outcome as well. I have updated to the most recent version of Pip (1.5.6) on Python 2.7.8 and this resolved the issue. Furthermore, I can install your required packages perfectly with this version of Pip and install your full package (Git repo) with the 2.7.8 interpretor directly. I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: I also tried to install (in a new clean Virtualenv) with the command `python setup.py develop` as you described on the Github bug report, it too works perfectly and installs without any error. Can this be related to your specific setup? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Hmm, one detail that might be missing is that our entire lab uses Mac OS X (currently, 10.10.1). I will add this to the description.

Comment: Not sure how it should work on OSX, but which Python interpretor gets setup in your Virtualenv? Also, could you try to create the virtualenv yourself (using the actual Virtualenv program (python-virtualenv), not mkvirtualenv if you have that under OSX). Then, once activated, run your setup in that Virtualenv? Also, I love the fact you guys have an actual lab!

Comment: I did as you suggested, but still ran into the same issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Mirrored from https://github.com/uwescience/myria-python/pull/35)

Multiple hours of 100's of Google searches eventually took me to this
numpy thread:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2434

for which they had to add numpy to `setup_requires` **AND** `install_requires` to fix a similar issue. Doing
this with requests seems to have worked. However, I am somewhat
skeptical as @Timusan indicated above not seeing our problem in the
first place.

I tried on my Mac as well as on Ubuntu, and am now able to
install from a clean virtualenv on both systems.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in the comments, the root cause is a buggy version of python / pip. This problem exists with python 2.7.6, but when I upgraded to 2.7.9 there was no longer a problem. Also beware that `mkirtualenv` by default uses the python in `/usr/bin/python`, even if there are other python versions further up in the `$PATH`.

Comment: Hmm. Our OS X has 2.7.9, and the virtualenv does use the brew-installed version of Python 2.7.9, not Apple's system 2.7.6.

`(myria-python)dhalperi@dhm myria-python % python --version` returns `Python 2.7.9`